# Opencv Library return null

Tags: android, opencv

When I Integrate Open cv in android Studio for Eye Detection. After Integration  Message print Opencv install successfully message Generate but after they given error .

> Couldn't load detection_based_tracker from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip
>   file"/data/app/com.example.admin.lanskart-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.admin.lanskart-2,/vendor/lib,/system/lib]]]:findLibrary
>   returned null

```
Process: com.example.admin.lanskart, PID: 24341
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load detection_based_tracker from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.lanskart-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.admin.lanskart-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:553)
        at com.example.admin.lanskart.MainActivity$1.onManagerConnected(MainActivity.java:69)
        at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$3.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:319)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1140)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1157)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you're not giving enough details to get an answer. What did you try? Did you check the path for missing library?  and so on. Imagine you're at our place and must solve this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the directories of your jni source in your gradle. Your app gradle should be like this:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "enter.your.packagename"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }


    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }

    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "ndklibrarysample"
        cppFlags += ["-std=c++11", "-fexceptions", "-frtti"]
        cppFlags  += "-I${file("D:yourpathtothesefiles/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString()
        ldLibs += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"]
        stl = "gnustl_static"
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\"

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so"
            }
        }
        create("armv7") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so"
            }
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "x86"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\x86\\"

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so"
            }
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters += "mips"

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\mips\\"

                ldLibs += libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so"
            }
        }
        create("fat") {

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':libraries:opencv')
}
```

and change your  classpath fromyour project gradle file to this version plus ensure ndk path your local.properties file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
```

Comment: your are most welcome .. :) so accept my answer (upvote it) @samyakjain

Comment: @samyakjain plz accept my answer if it helped or upvote it if you cant not accept it